# issues creating a weld joint within contact listener class

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I have set a contact listener that creates a weld joint when contact is established between two bodies. When the bodies touch I keep getting a SIGABRT pointing to the line

```
b2Assert(IsLocked() == false);
```

in the method

```
b2Joint* b2World::CreateJoint(const b2JointDef* def)
```

within the class

```
b2World.cpp
```

Here are the contact listener classes:
SubcContactListener.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Box2D.h"
#import "Spriter.h"
#import "CreateRope.h"

class SubcContactListener : public b2ContactListener    {
public:
void     *helloWorldLayer;

b2WeldJoint *weldJoint;
b2World *world;

void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact);
void EndContact(b2Contact* contact);
void createWeldJoint(b2Body* ABody ,b2Body* BBody);
//void destroyWeldJoint(b2WeldJoint *weldJoint);

};
```

SubcContactListener.mm:

```
#import "SubcContactListener.h"
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"


void SubcContactListener:: BeginContact(b2Contact *contact) {

}

void SubcContactListener:: EndContact(b2Contact *contact)   {
b2Fixture       *fixtureA = contact->GetFixtureA();
b2Fixture       *fixtureB = contact->GetFixtureB();
b2Body          *fixtureABody = fixtureA->GetBody();
b2Body          *fixtureBBody = fixtureB->GetBody();

// We don't care about collisions that don't involve two bodies.
if (helloWorldLayer && fixtureABody && fixtureBBody)
{

    if(fixtureABody != NULL && fixtureBBody != NULL){
        createWeldJoint(fixtureABody, fixtureBBody);
    }

}

}
void SubcContactListener:: createWeldJoint(b2Body* ABody ,b2Body* BBody)    {

// The sprite tag is 1 for the spriter sprite and 3 for the rope links.
if (ABody && BBody)
//{
    CCSprite            *bodyASprite = (CCSprite *) ABody->GetUserData();
    CCSprite            *bodyBSprite = (CCSprite *) BBody->GetUserData();
    NSInteger           bodyASpriteTag = bodyASprite.tag;
    NSInteger           bodyBSpriteTag = bodyBSprite.tag;

    if (((bodyASpriteTag == 1) && (bodyBSpriteTag == 3)) ||
        ((bodyASpriteTag == 3) && (bodyBSpriteTag == 1)))
    {

        //creation of weldjoint
        if ( ABody!= NULL && BBody != NULL) {


        b2WeldJointDef      weldJointDef;
        weldJointDef.Initialize(ABody,
                                BBody,
                                ABody->GetWorldCenter());
        weldJointDef.collideConnected = false;

        weldJoint = (b2WeldJoint*) ABody->GetWorld()->CreateJoint(&weldJointDef);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Also within the HelloWorldLayer.mm initPhysics method:

```
// Create contact listener
contactListener = new SubcContactListener();
contactListener->helloWorldLayer = self;
world->SetContactListener(contactListener);
```

From the error I think it has something to do with the weld joint, just not too sure. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to modify the world inside a callback. The assert statement is stating that it has locked the world to begin the simulation step so you are not allowed to perform that operation.

This problem is solved by caching the contact events and processing them after the simulation step.